# Feeding multiple rows of data into ANN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, artificial-intelligence, numpy

I've built an ANN from scratch, that works with one row of data with any number of neurons and hidden layers. For the setup I am using 2 hidden layers, 5 neurons (just while building). The network works when I supply it one row of data (with 4 components) and the categorical variable, however I am struggling to get my head around how the structure changes when I want to feed in multiple rows, $x$, each with $n$ components.

I am using numpy library in Python to implement the network. My variables and inputs are as follows:

```
self.input = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,5,1,2],[5,6,7,8]])
self.y = np.array([1,0,1]) #true y
weights_to_hidden = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1], self.neurons) #(4,5)
self.weights = [(self.neurons,self.neurons),(self.neurons,self.neurons)] 
#one weight matrix for each hidden layer, in my case 2, that is a square matrix of size neurons, in an array
self.weights_to_output = np.random.rand(self.neurons, self.input.shape[0]) #(5, 3)
```

> self.input.shape[0] = number of inputs
>
> self.input.shape[1] = components of each input
>
> self.neurons = 5

I am having issues understanding what sizes my matrices should have, because in its current state I end up with a $(3,3)$ or $(3,4)$ matrix as the output, rather than $(1,3)$ or $(3,1)$. Ideally, I should be able to feed in $x$ rows, each with $n$ components, and get $x$ outputs.

Let's denote

weights from input -> first hidden = $W_{h1}$,

weights from hidden 1 -> hidden2 = $W_{h2}$ and

weights from hidden2 -> output = $W_{o}$.

The activation function is sigmoid, noted $\sigma(x)$. Input is $[x]$ and the matrix of y values at each hidden layer is $[y]_{hn}$. The process of dot product is noted with $*$ operator.

Then, the process of one feedforward is:

1. $[y]_{h1} = \sigma([x]*W_{h1})$
2. $[y]_{h2} = \sigma([y]_{h1} * W_{h2})$
3. out = $\sigma([y]_{h2} * W_{o})$

These operations work, but for back propagation to also be compatible, I need to have one individual value for each input and I am not sure what to change in this procedure for it to be that way. This part of my linear algebra is a bit shaky so any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the weights are independent for each input, you need an extra dimension, i.e. a 3D tensor of 2D matrices.

If your current matrix is `(1,3)`, then you can pretend it's actually an array of matrices with only one element, i.e. shaped `(1,3,1)`, right? And so if you want `x` values, well, it'll be `(1,3,x)`.

That's the general idea - don't trust the exact order of indexing I'm using though, I always forget the numpy conventions for that.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what you mean

Comment: You have an array of arrays. What you need is an array of arrays of arrays., i.e. np.array([ [ [feature1_1, feature1_2], [feature2_1, feature2_2] ], [[feature1_1, feature1_2], [feature2_1, feature2_2] ] ])